# Release memory from ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(...)

Tags: buffer, directx-11

How do we release memory when a buffer is created using ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(...)?
My objective is to prevent memory leaks.

```
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> m_vertexBuffer;
    m_vertices = new std::vector<PNTVertex>();

    /*... fill m_vertices with vertices ...*/

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd = { 0 };
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { 0 };

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(PNTVertex)* m_verticesCount;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    initData.pSysMem = m_vertices->data();
    DX::ThrowIfFailed(
        device->CreateBuffer(&bd, &initData, &m_vertexBuffer)
        );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the call to `CreateBuffer` returns, Direct3D does not need your `std::vector` data accessible. Using `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` takes care of the rest. When it goes out of scope, it will call `Release` on the COM object returned from `CreateBuffer`. The COM object itself will get freed whenever the reference count hits zero.

The one thing to keep in mind here is that Direct3D uses a non-standard COM lifecyle model: once the Direct3D 11 device is destroyed, all the 'device children' objects created from it are immediately invalid even if they still have a non-zero reference count. Therefore, you usually explicitly clean up all the various COM objects just before you do the final release of the Direct3D device. With `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` you can do this with `Reset`.

See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx)